# Reading and updating sheets in an XLSM file using pandas while preserving the VBA code

Tags: python, excel, vba, pandas

I have a requirement to read an xlsm file and update some of the sheets in the file. I want to use pandas for this purpose.

I tried answers presented in the following post. I couldn't see the VBA macros when I add the VBA project back.
https://stackoverflow.com/posts/28170939/revisions

Here are the steps I tried,

Extracted the VBA_project.bin out of the original.xlsm file and then

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('original.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
workbook = writer.book
workbook.filename = 'test.xlsm'
workbook.add_vba_project('vbaProject.bin')
writer.save()
```

With this I don't see the VBA macros attached to "test.xlsm". The result is the same even if I write it to the "original.xlsm" file.

How do I preserve the VBA macros or add them back to the original xlsm file?

Also, is there a way I can open the "xlsm" file itself rather than the "xlsx" counterpart using `pd.ExcelWriter`?

Comment: I think you should use VBA for this, and NOT Python.  Just my .02.

Comment: The files are huge, also the intention is to merge one particular sheet of the original file to a recent update, say adding this month's data set to a yearly accumulated data sheet.

Answer (score 7):

You can do this easily with pandas

```
import pandas as pd
import xlrd

# YOU MUST PUT sheet_name=None TO READ ALL SHEETS IN YOUR XLSM FILE
df = pd.read_excel('YourFile.xlsm', sheet_name=None)

# prints all sheets
print(df)
```

Comment: This doesn't write back to the file, which is a key part of the question.

Answer (score 1):

Ah, I see.  I still can't tell what you are doing, but here are a few general samples of code to get Python to communicate with Excel.

```
Read contents of a worksheet in Excel:

import pandas as pd
from pandas import ExcelWriter
from pandas import ExcelFile

df = pd.read_excel('C:\\your_path\\test.xls', sheetname='Sheet1')

************************************************************************************

Use Python to run Macros in Excel:
import os
import win32com.client

#Launch Excel and Open Wrkbook
xl=win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")  
xl.Workbooks.Open(Filename="C:\your_path\excelsheet.xlsm") #opens workbook in readonly mode. 

#Run Macro
xl.Application.Run("excelsheet.xlsm!modulename.macroname") 

#Save Document and Quit.
xl.Application.Save()
xl.Application.Quit() 

#Cleanup the com reference. 
del xl
```

---

```
Write, from Python, to Excel:

import xlsxwriter

# Create an new Excel file and add a worksheet.
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('C:/your_path/ranges_and_offsets.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

# Widen the first column to make the text clearer.
worksheet.set_column('A:A', 20)

# Add a bold format to use to highlight cells.
bold = workbook.add_format({'bold': True})

# Write some simple text.
worksheet.write('A1', 'Hello')

# Text with formatting.
worksheet.write('A2', 'World', bold)

# Write some numbers, with row/column notation.
worksheet.write(2, 0, 123)
worksheet.write(3, 0, 123.456)


workbook.close()
```

---

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
wb = Workbook()

# grab the active worksheet
ws = wb.active

# Data can be assigned directly to cells
ws['A1'] = 42

# Rows can also be appended
ws.append([1, 2, 3])

# Python types will automatically be converted
import datetime
ws['A2'] = datetime.datetime.now()

# Save the file
wb.save("C:\\your_path\\sample.xlsx")
```

Comment: Thanks for the examples. My use case is inline with the second example you have provided.                                                                                                                            #workbook1  has 10 sheets                                                                                                                                workbook1 = xlsxwriter.Workbook('C:/your_path/test1.xlsm')                                                      #workbook2 has 1 sheet which needs to be merged with the corresponding sheet

Comment: in first file                                                                                                         workbook2 = xlsxwriter.Workbook('C:/your_path/test2.xlsm')                                                   I can actually treat both these files as "xlsx" by pulling vba_project.bin and do the merge. But when add the vba_project.bin back to the merged xlsx file and rename it to "xlsm", I don't see the macros. The VBA content didn't get applied

Comment: In `pandas.read_excel()` as of version .21, the option to specify the sheet name, is now `sheet_name` instead of `sheetname`.